# updating online db with json android

Tags: php, android, sql, json, android-volley

I'm trying to update my online Database from my Android app using JSON. If I try to do that, the SQL output says all the fields are empty, so it doesn't update anything. I tried changing the online code to have it test for the name instead of the id, but since both of them aren't filled in, that didn't help. Hope you can help? Here is the code (you'll be most interested in saveTask() function):

EditActivity:

```
package com.somthing.somepackage;

some imports...

public class EditActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText mNameEditText;
    EditText mReminderDateEditText;
    EditText mReminderTimeEditText;
    Bundle mCurrentTask;
    Intent intent;
    private static final String URL_POST = "https://my_site/json_put_data.php";
    private static final String URL_UPDATE = "https://my_site/json_update_data.php";
    private static final String URL_DELETE = "https://my_site/json_delete_data.php";

    private boolean mTaskHasChanged = false;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_edit);

        intent = getIntent();
        mCurrentTask = intent.getExtras();

        if (mCurrentTask == null) {
            setTitle(getString(R.string.editor_activity_title_new_task));

            invalidateOptionsMenu();
        } else {
            setTitle(getString(R.string.editor_activity_title_edit_task));
        }

        mNameEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_task_name);
        mReminderDateEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_task_reminder_date);
        mReminderTimeEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_task_reminder_time);

        mNameEditText.setOnTouchListener(mTouchListener);
        mReminderDateEditText.setOnTouchListener(mTouchListener);
        mReminderTimeEditText.setOnTouchListener(mTouchListener);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_edit, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
        if (mCurrentTask == null) {
            MenuItem menuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_delete);
            menuItem.setVisible(false);
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_save:
                postData();
                finish();
                return true;
            case R.id.action_delete:
                showDeleteConfirmationDialog();
                return true;
            case android.R.id.home:
                if (!mTaskHasChanged) {
                    NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(EditActivity.this);
                    return true;
                }

                DialogInterface.OnClickListener discardButtonClickListener =
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                            NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(EditActivity.this);
                        }
                    };

            showUnsavedChangesDialog(discardButtonClickListener);
            return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (!mTaskHasChanged) {
        super.onBackPressed();
        return;
    }

    DialogInterface.OnClickListener discardButtonClickListener =
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                    finish();
                }
            };

    showUnsavedChangesDialog(discardButtonClickListener);
}

private void showUnsavedChangesDialog(
    DialogInterface.OnClickListener discardButtonClickListener) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setMessage(R.string.unsaved_changes_dialog_msg);
    builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.discard, discardButtonClickListener);
    builder.setNegativeButton(R.string.keep_editing, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            if (dialog != null) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        }
    });

    AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
    alertDialog.show();
}

private void showDeleteConfirmationDialog() {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setMessage(R.string.delete_dialog_msg);
    builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.delete, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            deleteTask();
        }
    });
    builder.setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            if (dialog != null) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        }
    });

    AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
    alertDialog.show();
}

private void deleteTask() {
    if (mCurrentTask != null) {
        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);  

        StringRequest dr = new StringRequest(Request.Method.DELETE,
                URL_DELETE,
                new Response.Listener<String>()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        Log.i("delete: ", response);
                        Toast.makeText(EditActivity.this, getString(R.string.editor_delete_task_successful),
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Toast.makeText(EditActivity.this, getString(R.string.editor_delete_task_failed),
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
        );
        queue.add(dr);

        finish();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onPostCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);

    if (mCurrentTask == null) {
        return;
    }

    String name = intent.getExtras().getString("NAME");
    String remDate = intent.getExtras().getString("REMINDERDATE");
    String remTime = intent.getExtras().getString("REMINDERTIME");

    mNameEditText.setText(name);
    mReminderDateEditText.setText(remDate);
    mReminderTimeEditText.setText(remTime);

    saveTask();
}

private void saveTask() {
    String nameString = mNameEditText.getText().toString().trim();
    String dateString = mReminderDateEditText.getText().toString().trim();
    String timeString = mReminderTimeEditText.getText().toString().trim();

    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(nameString) && TextUtils.isEmpty(dateString) &&
            TextUtils.isEmpty(timeString)) {
        return;
    }

    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);  // this = context

    StringRequest putRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.PUT,
        URL_UPDATE,
        new Response.Listener<String>()
        {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                Log.d("Response", response);
            }
        },
        new Response.ErrorListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.d("Error.Response", String.valueOf(error));
            }
        }
    )
        {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams()
            {
                Map<String, String>  params = new HashMap<String, String> ();
                params.put("id", String.valueOf(getIntent().getExtras().getInt("id")));
                params.put("name", "Android Test insert");

                return params;
            }
        };

        queue.add(putRequest);
    };

private void postData(){
    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

    StringRequest postRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,
            URL_POST,
            new Response.Listener<String>()
            {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    Log.d("Response postData: ", response);
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Log.d("Error.Response", String.valueOf(error));
                }
            }
    ) {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams()
        {
            Map<String, String>  params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("id", "null");
            params.put("name", "Android Test update");

            return params;
        }
    };
    queue.add(postRequest);
}

private View.OnTouchListener mTouchListener = new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
        mTaskHasChanged = true;
        return false;
    }
};
}
```

Online code:

```
<?php

$host = "localhost";
$username = "my_un";
$password = "my_pw";
$db = "my_db";

$id = $_POST["id"];
$name = $_POST["name"];

$sql = "UPDATE table_name SET name = '$name' WHERE id = '$id';";

$con = mysqli_connect($host, $username, $password, $db);

$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

if($result){
    echo $sql;
}
else {
    echo "nok";
}

mysqli_close($con);

?>
```

Output SQL statement:

```
UPDATE items SET name = '' WHERE id = '';
//Here is the problem, name and id are empty
```

Comment: You're sending a `PUT` request from volley but trying to check for `POST` request parameters in the PHP Code. Try using `Request.Method.POST` instead of `Request.Method.PUT` when making the Volley request

Comment: Ok, that helped a bit, only now it inserts instead of updating the existing one.

Comment: Your update query seems to be okay, Can you print the value of `$sql` with a dummy `$name` value? Does executing the same query directly from the SQL CLI have the correct behaviour?

Comment: Yes, if I put the query directly in the SQL on my Database, it updates the row, as espected.

Comment: Interesting, try debugging again. The issue doesn't seem to be with the part of the code you put up here. All the issues should ideally be resolved by changing the PUT request to POST from volley. If that solves the question, I'd be happy to write an answer indicating the same.

Comment: Ok, I'll do a debug again. I love to search for a problem anyway (I've had this problem for a few days before I posted it), it's the best way to learn. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is because your php server is expecting `id` and `name` as `POST` parameters but your android volley request is sending a `PUT` request instead in the `saveTask()` method. Updating it to `POST` method as follows

```
StringRequest putRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,
        URL_UPDATE,
        new Response.Listener<String>()
        {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                Log.d("Response", response);
            }
        },
        ....
```